# How to annotate integer as a ForeignKey in django?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have this model:

```py
class Order(Model):
    sale_address = ForeignKey(Address)
    purchase_address = ForeignKey(Address)
```

and want to conditionally annotate one address or another depending on some condition, as a ForeignKey:

```
order = Order.objects.annotate(
    address=...  # sale_address if current user is seller
).first()

assert isinstance(order.address, Address)  # True
```

How can I do that?

I've tried this:

```
annotate(
    address_id=Case(
        When(
            user_role='SELLER',
            then=F('sale_address'),
        ),
        When(
            user_role='BUYER',
            then=F('purchase_address'),
        ),
    ),
)
```

but in this case `address_id` is just an integer and I get N+1 issues when making list of orders with `address.region`.

Comment: It's probably just better to prefetch/select_related both `sale_address` and `purchase_address`, and access either depending on the user role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@AKX says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73688570/how-to-annotate-integer-as-a-foreignkey-in-django/73694777#comment130124293_73688570), it is likely better to just [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) the two `Address`es, and then use a `@property` to determine which one to use, so:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user_role = …
    sale_address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sale_orders'
    )
    purchase_address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='purchase_orders'
    )

    @property
    def address(self):
        if self.user_role == 'SELLER':
            return self.sale_address
        if self.user_role == 'BUYER':
            return self.purchase_address
```